# Hydrogen bond comparison

Tags: hydrogen-bond

How do you compare the strength of H bonds when it's the same atom on both sides of the H? Like $\ce{N-H\bond{...}N}$ vs $\ce{F-H\bond{...}F}$? Is one still stronger than the other, or are they both the same since in both cases the pull on both sides is equal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some cases, such as [F-H-F]- ([biflouride](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifluoride)), there is a [symmetric hydrogen bond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_hydrogen_bond), with both H-F bonds equally strong.

However, just because the two atoms bonding to the H are the same doesn't mean it is a symmetric hydrogen bond.  For example [water dimer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_dimer) does not have a symmetrical hydrogen bond, the H is closer to one O atom than the other.

There can be cases where the hydrogen being exactly in the middle is a potential energy minimum, and other cases where the middle is not a local minimum but there are two minima offset from the middle.

See [Symmetry of hydrogen bonds in solution](http://pac.iupac.org/publications/pac/pdf/2009/pdf/8104x0571.pdf) for more information.